# 2003 Ford Escort ZX2 has creaky steering

Tags: power-steering, steering

It doesn't squeal. It creaks in a constant, staccato fashion while I make right turns at low speeds.  What could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suspect worn tie rod ends.  Grab hold of one and give it a twist and see if there's any play.  If it's not too worn, you may be able to grease it and avoid replacement.

You should also check your power steering fluid, but if that's low I'd expect it would creak on both left and right turns.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to do this (read: I probably couldn't find them with a floodlight and a Haynes manual), but I appreciate your suspicions.  I've had the tie rod ends replaced within the last couple years; I will check my records to be sure.

Comment: You could ask someone to check to see if they need to be lubed.  Another possibility is your sway bar.  If your bushings are starting to get hard or worn, they could creak as the weight transfers to one end.  You should be able to check this by pushing down on the left front corner of the car.  If it creaks or groans, that may be your culprit.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I will have it looked at as soon as I can so that I might avoid replacement as you say.